# What is [....] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object

I ended up accidentally doing the equivalent of this in Ruby the other night:

```ruby
a = *1..5  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a << a
a          # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]
a.last     # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]
```

What is `[...]` and what can I do with it?

Comment: I guess it's just a presentation markup, not valid syntax. Concerning recursive arrays - I've never used them.

Comment: hah, haven't seen this before :)

Comment: It's human for "omg so much output". Not sure what the question is, though, what " reference " are you referring to?

Comment: How did I manage to suggest _this_ as a duplicate? I meant to follow Anderw's suggestion. Sorry

Comment: -1 for sloppiness. `a` should not appear as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [....]]`, it appears as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]`.

Comment: It most certainly shows as `[....]` in irb (1.9.3) for me. I know this because that's where I cut'n'pasted it from.

Comment: Sorry if that is the case. But on my irb 1.9.3, it shows as `[...]`.

Comment: Seems to be the wirble gem (for colorizing) that turns it from `[...]` to `[....]`. Editing the question since wirble isn't standard.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something there, +1. See comment by Andrew Marshall above to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the way Array.inspect displays recursive arrays. The last Element of a is a itself. If a where displayed after 5, inspect would end up in an endless loop:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]]]]
```